# d3.js force-collapsible with labels

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I am having some trouble trying to re-create

I've attempted to add the features of http://bl.ocks.org/950642 to http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html

and tried to do:

```
node.enter().append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name });
```

However that results in the circles disappearing and all the text is clumped in the top left corner.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Here is my JS:

here is a jsfiddle: for some reason it isn't working though here because of the .json file I think...

http://jsfiddle.net/vMw2N/5/

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    node,
    link,
    root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .on("tick", tick)
    .charge(function(d) { return d._children ? -d.size / 100 : -30; })
    .linkDistance(function(d) { return d.target._children ? 80 : 30; })
    .size([width, height]);

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("../data/flare.json", function(json) {
  root = json;
  root.fixed = true;
  root.x = width / 2;
  root.y = height / 2;
  update();
});

function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update the links…
  link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links.
  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  // Exit any old links.
  link.exit().remove();

  // Update the nodes…
  node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
      .style("fill", color);

  node.transition()
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.children ? 4.5 : Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10; });

  // Enter any new nodes.
  node.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.children ? 4.5 : Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10; })
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);


    node.enter().append("text")
            .attr("class","node")
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
            .on("click",click)
            .text(function(d){return d.name})
            .call(force.drag);

  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

// Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update();
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.size = node.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + recurse(v); }, 0);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
    return node.size;
  }

  root.size = recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}
```

Comment: Hi, it would be great to remove all the non-necessary (for the question) code from your example.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.webashlar.com/Demos/D3/index.html) is combination of both graph.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have been able to fix the problem by adding a transform call in the `tick()` function

```
node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

//node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; });
//    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
```

Comment: I had a similar problem.  It looks like cx and cx are only for the centers of circle shapes.  If you group it with a label, you have a g which doesn't have a c for center.  I used this too to fix the position of nodes, but what did you do to update the links?  If you move nodes offscreen, these disattach themselves from the nodes.  Did you transform them somehow too?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it come from the fact that you call 2 times `node.enter()`?
You call it once before appending the circle and once before appending the text.

Try to replace the line `node.enter().append("text")` by:

```
node.append("text")
```